# Unity object orientation in player hand changes depending on angle of object pick up

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I have a character that is able to pick up the axe in the game.  For some reason, if approach the item from different angles, the player picks up the axe in a different position.  Why does this happen if I have made it so the axe appears in the players hand.  I use the axe's center transform position and place it on the parent object which is the hand.  I would of at least expected some consistency since it should not be random due to the code.

```
testObject = Instantiate(toCreate) as GameObject;
testObject.transform.parent = arm.transform;
testObject.transform.position = arm.transform.position;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    testObject = Instantiate(toCreate) as GameObject;
    testObject.transform.parent = arm.transform;
    testObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    testObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

Comment: This seemed to work for the axe, but for other items i have, similar to the axe, need to be rotated vertically, it does not seem to work.  
I looked up Quaternion.identity; This quaternion corresponds to "no rotation" - the object is perfectly aligned with the world or parent axes.  Does this mean that this is saying do not rotate the object at all?

Comment: If the axe is only follow parent , it's localRotaion can be a constant value , I just set identity for example , You can set any value. for example: `Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)` to rotaion vertically in your case.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html  
LocalRotaion Description : "The rotation of the transform 'relative to' the transform rotation of the parent"

Comment: Thanks Tim, i was able to play with Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0) and got it correct for my items.  It works correctly 90% of time.  However I am still able to approach the object from a different angle and it will reverse the image, with the axe blade on the bottom.  Is there a way to make it so that Unity can know what is top vs bottom, since sometimes 90,0,0,0 will reverse the axe in wrong direction if approached and grabbed at wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour will change depending on when you make it a child of another object ( set a parent).
Probably best idea is to set position and rotation before setting a parent.